# How to populate FXML tableview with an Observable List

Tags: tableview, fxml, observablelist

So far I have created a GUI using JavaFX SceneBuilder, which includes an anchor pane containing a two-column TableView.
I have linked events on GUI objects (eg buttons) to event handling code in the FXMLDocumentController. In the controller, when a selected button is clicked, I create an ObservableList from a table stored in an embedded derby database. That works fine.

I'm simply stuck on populating the TableView with the Observable list and despite extensive searches and tutorials I can't find a coherent suggestion that works to achieve the above or even if it is achievable

Comment: The [makery JavaFX tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part2/) explains how to populate an FXML TableView from an observable list.  I doubt you will get a better answer or suggestion here.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this one for several hours without getting it to work or discovering why it wouldn't work.

Comment: For example, the makery tutorial fails at the end of ch 1 when one tries to run the app. It produces the following:            javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/D:/J2EE/AddressApp/dist/run1222686315/AddressApp.jar!/address/view/PersonOverview.fxml:11 and a dump that is too large to enclose here. I'm trying this in Netbeans 8.0.2, I notice makery develops the app in Eclipse. But I cant see why this should be a problem,

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem to be the PersonOverview AnchorPane Controller class was pointing to a different project. I set the attribute to Empty and the app worked.